# Parse.com - Promises - Return the parent object with other one-to-one object as a property

Tags: parse-platform

I have 2 tables in parse
Memories and Locations with a relation One-To-One, but the pointer is in Location table ( Pointer  )

What i need is to read all memories ten by ten with skip and limit and for each memory to atach a property with location object

By now i have this:

```
var _ = require('underscore.js');
Parse.Cloud.define("feed", function(request, response) {
    var memories = Parse.Object.extend("Memories");
    var memoriesQuery = new Parse.Query(memories);

    memoriesQuery.skip(0);//request.params.skip);
    memoriesQuery.limit(10);//request.params.limit);
    memoriesQuery.descending("createdAt");
    memoriesQuery.include("group");

    var parsedResults = [];

    memoriesQuery.find().then(function(memories) {

        var promise = Parse.Promise.as();
        _.each(memories, function(memory) {

            promise = promise.then(function() {
                var locations = Parse.Object.extend("Locations");
                var locationsQuery = new Parse.Query(locations);
                locationsQuery.equalTo("memory", memory);

                var subPromise = Parse.Promise();

                locationsQuery.first().then(function(location) {
                    memory["location"] = location;
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(memory) + " ........ " + memory["location"]);
                    console.log("=============");
                    parsedResults.push(memory);
                    subPromise.resolve(memory);
                });
                return subPromise ;
            });
            console.log("-----------");
            console.log("Promise:" +promise.toString());
        });

        return promise;

    }).then(function(){
        response.success(parsedResults);
    });
});
```

I have no clue what to do.. More than 10 hours of tries.
I appreciate any help!

Comment: but the pointer is in Location table ( Pointer ) ... then you should be querying 'location' with an include on the field name contains the pointer to memory.

Comment: i need this way because location is one of the tables i need to join, but i have two more with one-to-many and if i get a solution for .first() it is easy to make for .find() . That's way i need a way to solve it this way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally solved!
Maybe it will help somebody.

Solution:

```
var _ = require('underscore.js');
var memoriesResult = [];
Parse.Cloud.define("feed", function(request, response) {
    var promises = [];
    var promise = findMemories();
    promise.then(function(memories){
        console.log("success promise!!");
        _.each(memories, function (memory) {
            console.log("each");
            promises.push(findLocation(memory));
        });
        return Parse.Promise.when(promises);
    }).then(function(){
        console.log("Finish");
        response.success(memoriesResult);
    }, function(error){
        console.error("Promise Error: " + error.message);
        response.error(error);
    });
});

function findMemories(){
    console.log("Enter findMemories");

    var memories = Parse.Object.extend("Memories");
    var memoriesQuery = new Parse.Query(memories);

    memoriesQuery.skip(0);//request.params.skip);
    memoriesQuery.limit(10);//request.params.limit);
    memoriesQuery.descending("createdAt");
    memoriesQuery.include("group");

    var promise = new Parse.Promise();

    memoriesQuery.find().then(function(memories) {
        console.log("Memories found!");
        promise.resolve(memories);
    }, function(error) {
        promise.reject(error);
    });
    return promise;
}

function findLocation(memory) {
    console.log("Enter findLocation");

    var locations = Parse.Object.extend("Locations");
    var locationsQuery = new Parse.Query(locations);
    locationsQuery.equalTo("memory", memory);

    var promise = new Parse.Promise();

    locationsQuery.first().then(function(location) {
        console.log("Location found");
        memoriesResult.push({"memory": memory, "location" : location});
        promise.resolve(memory);
    }, function(error) {
        promise.reject(error);
    });
    return promise;
}
```

Comment: I would strongly recommend against doing another `find()` inside a loop, that really will not scale well. You will be executing lots of queries (if `request.params.limit==10` you will execute 11 queries)

Answer (score 0):

After doing some experiments, I've come up with the following requirements and solution:

- You want to page through `Memories` items a page at a time, sorted by their `createdAt`
- You want the `Locations` related to each memory
- You are limited by the fact that the relationship is `Locations->Memories`

Your first step is to define the query for memories:

```
var memoryQuery = new Parse.Query('Memories');
memoryQuery.skip(request.params.skip);
memoryQuery.skip(request.params.limit);
memoryQuery.descending('createdAt');
```

You can now use this query to limit the `Locations` objects returned. If your links are all setup correctly you will get back 10 records:

```
var locationQuery = new Parse.Query('Locations');
// limit to only the page of Memory items requested
locationQuery.matchesQuery('memory', memoryQuery);
// include the Memory pointer's data
locationQuery.include('memory');
var memoriesResult = [];
locationQuery.find().then(function(locations) {
    var result = _.map(locations, function(location) {
        memory: location.get('memory'),
        location: location
    });
    response.success(result);
}, function(error) {
    response.error(error);
});
```

The only issue with the above is that I'm not sure on the order of the returned records, so you might want to re-sort them before returning them. That is extremely simple though with the underscore library.

This will result in 2 queries no matter the page size.

Comment: True. But beside to location table wich is one to one i have two more wich are one to many, and instead of .first() method i use .find() and there i can't use your method. Thanks for time to answer!